# Project DLL in BIN directory Access is Denied

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010, I am having an error below. The application was running in debug mode with no problem and now having this error when I debug. I got latest from TFS in my solution and did not alter permissions because this was working. Did anybody have an experience like this?

1>CSC : error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\TFS\AppInventoryUpgrade\AppInventoryUpgrade\obj\Debug\AppInventoryUpgrade.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '

Comment: Did you try modifying the conf files to require higher premissions?

Comment: The application is probably running already. You need to close it (or even kill the process) before you can recompile.

Comment: @Luaan I have stopped the process and even rebooted my computer. I tried again with the same error.

Comment: @A.Abramov - yep you were right